# The emulator process for AVD Pixel_XL_API_27 has terminated, emulator not working

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-emulator, avd-manager

My emulator is not working. I am so frustrated I have almost done all the solutions but nothing works. I'm facing an issue with my Android Virtual Device (AVD) that was previously working fine but suddenly stopped working with the following error log:

```
2023-11-26 15:38:08,596 [9032513]   INFO - #com.android.tools.idea.devicemanager.DeviceManagerAndroidDebugBridge - []
2023-11-26 15:38:30,262 [9054179]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 27 - "C:\Users\CITY COMPUTERs\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe" -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Pixel_6_Pro_API_27 -qt-hide-window -grpc-use-token -idle-grpc-timeout 300
2023-11-26 15:38:30,372 [9054289]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 27 - Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
2023-11-26 15:38:30,372 [9054289]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 27 - Found systemPath C:\Users\CITY COMPUTERs\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-27\google_apis\x86\
2023-11-26 15:38:30,697 [9054614]   WARN - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 27 - Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\CITY COMPUTERs\.android\avd\Pixel_6_Pro_API_27.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading.
2023-11-26 15:38:32,980 [9056897]   INFO - Emulator: Pixel 6 Pro API 27 - Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
2023-11-26 15:38:33,316 [9057233]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_6_Pro_API_27 is online, assuming it's not
2023-11-26 15:38:33,316 [9057233]   WARN - #com.android.tools.idea.avdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Unable to determine if Pixel_XL_API_27 is online, assuming it's not
```

Steps I've taken:

- Rebooted my system.
- Checked for Android SDK updates and emulator updates.
- Deleted and recreated the AVD.
- Tried running with different emulator settings.

However, the issue persists. Can someone please provide insights or potential solutions to resolve this sudden termination of the Android emulator?